# Convert Type of DevExpress.XtraTreelist.TreeListMultislection to System.Collections.CollectionBase

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress-windows-ui

How I Convert the `DevExpress.XtraTreelist.TreeListMultislection` to `System.Collections.CollectionBase`. CollectionBase is Provide the abstract base class for strongly typed collection.

```
foreach (TreeListNode treeListNode in (CollectionBase)this.treeListWells.Selection)
            {
                int num2 = Util.Obj2Int((object)treeListNode.GetDisplayText((object)"TypeShow"));
                if (num1 < 0)
                    num1 = num2;
                if (num1 == num2)
                {
                    if (Util.Obj2Long((object)treeListNode.GetDisplayText((object)"Id")) > 0L)
                        list.Add((object)treeListNode);
                    if (num2 == 55)
                        list.Add((object)treeListNode);
                    if (num2 == 60)
                        list.Add((object)treeListNode);
                    if (num2 == 65)
                        list.Add((object)treeListNode);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is with all those casts to `object`? They serve no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A `DevExpress.XtraTreelist.TreeListMultislection` is *not* a `CollectionBase` and so you can not cast it into one. In your case, there is also no need for such a cast, since it is an `IEnumerable<TreeListNode>`, which is enough in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (TreeListNode treeListNode in this.treeListWells.Selection)
{
    //...
}
```